# Meteor JS как сделать глобальную переменную?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, global-variables

Я не как не могу уже неделю получить глобальную переменную , которую потом нужно будет менять и сравнивать с областью ввода текста (нужен баланс который сравнивается со ставкой и всегда изменяется при выигрыше или проигрыше) 
У меня пока так (2 одинаковых запроса , но во 2 выдаёт значение , а во 2 не хочет , пишет не может прочитать свойство started):

начало кода:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    var oneUser = Animals.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0];
    console.log(oneUser); 
    userAnimals = oneUser.started;
    console.log(userAnimals);
    return 0;

});

Template.hello.helpers({
    counter() { 
    var oneUser = Animals.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0];
    console.log(oneUser);
    if(oneUser){ 
    userAnimals = oneUser.started; 
    console.log(userAnimals);
    } 
    return 0;
    }
});
```

Вот выброс

```
undefined
main.js:12

 undefined
main.js:12 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'started' of undefined
    at main.js:12
    at maybeReady (meteor.js?hash=33066830ab46d87e2b249d2780805545e40ce9ba:927)
    at HTMLDocument.loadingCompleted (meteor.js?hash=33066830ab46d87e2b249d2780805545e40ce9ba:939)
(anonymous) @ main.js:12
maybeReady @ meteor.js?hash=33066830ab46d87e2b249d2780805545e40ce9ba:927
loadingCompleted @ meteor.js?hash=33066830ab46d87e2b249d2780805545e40ce9ba:939

main.js:21 {_id: ObjectID, firsname: "Barsik", lastname: "Reshetnik", started: "122"}
main.js:21 

122
```

Comment: скорее всего что-то не так с запросами в Mongo.

Comment: вместо запросов к базе впишите какое-то значение/объект и у вас не должно быть ошибок, проверьте.

Comment: и кстати не может прочитать свойство started по той причине, что oneUser = undefined, а у undefined нет свойства started.

Comment: Но оно есть , почему одинаковые запросы и в одном есть , а в другом нет ??Почему в 1 раз оно пустой курсор выдаёт , а когда всё делается в хелпере всё работает ? Зачем мне вписывать значение\объект если мне нужно значение с базы (то есть баланс пользователя)

Comment: undefined - это не пустой курсор, это вообще не курсор.

Comment: Если убрать llimit и fetch тогда покажет курсор какой-то

Comment: а что показывает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вместо `.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0]` поставьте findOne().
2. Философия Метеор - data-on-wire. Т.е. вы имеете неполную копию БД на клиенте. Реализуется это через publications и subscriptions.

Publication:  вы описываете, какие данные хочешь видеть/обновлять на клиенте, когда он подписался на эту публикацию.
Например, когда вы подпишитесь на эту публикацию, документ в коллекции `Animal` с `_id='sdfvsdvsfdv'` на клиенте будут автоматически обновляться:

```
Meteor.publish("myGlobalAnimal", function(){
    return Animal.findOne({_id: "sdfvsdvsfdv"});
  });
```

Subscription: вы определяете, какие данные (из БД) вы хотите видеть и обновлять на клиенте. (Выбираете подписки) Например, если вы подписались на `myGlobalAnimal`, то на клиенте в БД в коллекции `Animal` у вас точно будет документ с `_id='sdfvsdvsfdv'`. Этот документ будет обновляться автоматически, при изменении БД на сервере.

Подписка:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myGlobalAnimal');
```

После подписки, вы можете найти этот документ:

```
let globalAnimal = Animal.findOne({_id: "sdfvsdvsfdv"});
```

Можете почитать про [publish and subscribe](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe)

Answer (score 0):

1. Пользоваться пакетом [Session Persistent](https://atmospherejs.com/cultofcoders/persistent-session)
2. > ```
   > Meteor.publish("myGlobalAnimal", function(){
   >     return Animal.findOne({});
   >   });
   > ```

Но нужно будет подписываться на клиентской стороне `Meteor.subscribe()`-ом

3. Через метод достаете

   > Meteor.methods({
   >           'getMyGlobalAnimal': function() {
   >             return myAnimal;
   >            }
   >       });